# How to Get the Size of the GrideItem View in LazyVGrid or Showing a Number Near the Corner of a View

Tags: ios, swiftui, overlay, lazyvgrid

I have a bunch of `Buttons` in `LazyVGrid` as shown in the picture below.  I want to show a number near the top-left corner of a button.  For a particular iOS device model, I can just offset the position of a number.  But this approach can be terribly wrong if I have an iPad.  Is there a way of getting the size of the `GridItem` `View`?  If there isn't, is there an effective way of showing a number near the top-left corner regardless of the device model?  Thanks.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let cols = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: cols) {
            ForEach(0...30, id: \.self) { item in
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "\(item).circle.fill")
                         .resizable()
                         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                         .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    
                }
                .overlay {
                    Text("0")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        .offset(x: -20, y: -20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `overlay` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)) takes an `alignment` argument which defaults to `.center`. Try passing `.topLeading` instead of using `.offset`:

```
Button { } label: {
    Image(systemName: "\(item).circle.fill")
         .resizable()
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         .foregroundColor(.orange)
    
}
.overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ADD THIS
    Text("0")
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
}
```

Comment: I guess I still need a small adjustment with `offset(x:y:)`, but I guess that alignment thing will largely do it.  Thanks.